# Setting a webView font

Tags: android, webview, fonts

Hi I have a problem setting the font of a web view inside my application.
This is the code I'm using:

```
  holder.info.loadDataWithBaseURL("", MessageFormat.format("<body link={0}><span style=\"color:{1};font-family:{2}; line-height: 1.6;\">{3}</span></body>", new String[]{String.valueOf(ColorManager.generalColorHEX), String.valueOf(ColorManager.colorNameActivityCellHEX), "Brandon_light",pins.get(position).getSnippet().toString()}), DataManager.mimeType, DataManager.encoding, "");
```

but the font does not change inside the web view.
I have already imported the font inside the app.

Font included:
[image: font included]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html add css before body like this

```
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont';
    src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/Brandon_light.otf');
  }

  body {
    font-family: 'MyWebFont', Fallback, sans-serif;
  }
```

Now your font will work perfectly.